# How to retrieve and change a value of an attribute of the pack geometry manager?

Tags: python, tkinter, call, pack

I'm working on a game where i want the image of the winner to expand its width in an animation so it fills the entire frame at the end. I got the following code to work already, but i need this for some more images and don't want to create a width-variable for each image. Instead i'd like to retrieve its ipadx-value directly and also change it that way.

After Player X wins, I set the `anim` variable to 1, and the animation gets executed:

```
# Create Player Info Window:
playerinfowindow=Frame(root, bg='black')
playerinfowindow.pack(side=TOP, fill='both', ipady=3)

playerX=Button(playerinfowindow, bd=0, bg=player[0].color)
iconX=PhotoImage(file='playerX.png')
playerX.config(image=iconX)

width = 84
anim = 0

def px():
    global width
    global anim
    if width < 252:
        width += anim    
    playerX.pack(side=LEFT, ipadx=width)
    playerX.after(10, px)

px()
```

I want to change the `px()` function to something like this:

```
def px():
    global anim
    if playerX['ipadx'] < 252:
        playerX['ipadx'] += anim    
    playerX.pack(side=LEFT, ipadx=84)
    playerX.after(10, px)
```

Answer (score 0):

[pack_info](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_info-method) will give you that information.

Comment: What if you want to change the options used when packed the widget? For example, you packed it `fill="both"` and now you just want `fill="x"`.. Can we use [pack_configure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_configure-method)? On effbot, it is saying it's the same as `pack`, but why there are 2 methods that do the same thing?